# passing values from radiobutton?

Tags: php, yii, radiobuttonlist

I have a `radiobutton` list in `yii` php,but I don't know how to access the value from this it doesn't contain any name or identity

```
<?php
echo $form->radioButtonList($model,'priority', 
                        array('C'=>'CRITICAL','H'=>'HIGH','L'=>'LOW')
 array('separator'=>'')); 
?>
```

Please help me to sort out this. thanks

Comment: it seems priority is the name.

Comment: I guess OP wants to know that how can we get the radiobutton's value using yii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do this to see the value 

`<?php echo $form->error($model, 'priority'); ?>`
[For your help](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/110/styling-radio-buttons/)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the form builder in Yii it sets the names and ids in a certain way. Lets say your `$model` is an instance of `User`, in this case your html name attribute would be `User[priority]` and can be accessed as $_POST['User']['priority']. The html id attribute doesn't use arrays so it is `User_priority`. So one of the radio buttons would look like this:

```
<input type='radio' name='User[priority]' id='User_priority' value='C'> CRITICAL
```

You can always look at the html source code generated to see this.